# How to replace string in only a certain number of non-consecutive rows

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with a column in it as follows

```
mydf<-data.frame(c("Normal study","Normal study","Normal study","Odd things","Strange stuff","Normal study","Normal study","Normal study"))
```

I want to replace "Normal study" with "Bizarre" but only in a random third of rows with "Normal study" so that the output is:

```
"Normal study"
"Normal study"
"Bizarre"
"Odd things"
"Strange stuff"
"Bizarre"
"Normal study"
"Normal study"
```

I tried something like

```
library(dplyr)

replaceWithBarr<-filter(grepl("Normal",out))
sample_n(replaceWithBarr,nrow(replaceWithBarr)/3)
```

to initially subset the data but it doesn't keep the row number so I can remerge the subsetted data... and I havent even got to the replace part yet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to do this exactly on 1/3 of the rows, or randomly with 33% chance?

In the first case:

```
mydf[sample(which(mydf[,1]=="Normal study"), sum(mydf[,1]=="Normal study")/3), 1] <- "Bizzare"
```

In the second case:

```
mydf[mydf[,1]=="Normal study" & runif(nrow(mydf), 0, 3) > 2, 1] <- "Bizzare"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in base R. Here I am assuming that you want to replace 0.3 of your "Normal study" entries with "Bizarre".

```
# Your sample data
mydf<-data.frame(c("Normal study","Normal study","Normal study","Odd things","Strange stuff","Normal study","Normal study","Normal study"));

# Convert factors to characters
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, as.character);

# Replace 0.3 of all "Normal study" entries with "Bizarre" 
set.seed(2017);
mydf[
    sample(which(mydf[, 1] == "Normal study"), floor(length(mydf[, 1] == "Normal study") * 0.33)),
    1] <- "Bizarre";
mydf;
#  c..Normal.study....Normal.study....Normal.study....Odd.things...
#1                                                     Normal study
#2                                                     Normal study
#3                                                          Bizarre
#4                                                       Odd things
#5                                                    Strange stuff
#6                                                     Normal study
#7                                                     Normal study
#8                                                          Bizarre
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
mydf<-data.frame(x=c("Normal study","Normal study","Normal study","Odd things","Strange stuff","Normal study","Normal study","Normal study"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
i <- which(mydf$x=="Normal study")
j <- sample(i, length(i)/3)
mydf[j, "x"] <- "Bizarre"
mydf
# > mydf
#               x
# 1  Normal study
# 2  Normal study
# 3       Bizarre
# 4    Odd things
# 5 Strange stuff
# 6  Normal study
# 7  Normal study
# 8       Bizarre
```